# Need to check min,max and sup for this set!

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

For this set I wanted to check :

minS=doesn't exist

maxS=2

supS=2

Answer (score 1):

Since $\min\left\{\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi\sqrt n}{2}\right)\right\}$ obtains a minimum when $n=2^2,6^2,10^2,14^2,...$ of $-1$ and $\dfrac{2}{n}$ is decreasing and nonnegative, then this implies that no minimum will ever be attained because as $n\to\infty$, $\dfrac{2}{n}\to 0$ but will never reach $0$.  Therefore, $\min S$ **approaches** $-1$, but never gets there.  This implies $\inf\left\{\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi\sqrt n}{2}\right)+\dfrac{2}{n}\right\}=-1.$

Since $\max\left\{\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi\sqrt n}{2}\right)\right\}=1$ when $n=4^2,8^2,12^2,16^2,...$ then the highest value $S$ can attain would be $1+\dfrac{2}{4^2}=1+\dfrac18=\dfrac98$ again because $\dfrac{2}{n}$ is decreasing.  Now, if we look at when $\dfrac{2}{n}$ attains its max, then it is clear that its max is when $n=1$.  So when $n=1$, $\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi\sqrt{1}}{2}\right)=0\implies S=2.$  Since $\dfrac{2}{n}$ is decreasing, then we can conclude that the values of $S$ will always be smaller than $1$ with increasing $n$.  Since $2\in S\implies\max S=2\implies\sup S=2.$